# CSS id's not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style two Bootstrap panels slightly differently. I decided to do this by naming them with different id's and then styling them via CSS. For some reason the CSS id selector is not working for me.

Here is the HTML:

```
           <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="price" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Price</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">{{ item[0][3] }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div id="size" class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Size</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">{{ item[0][2] }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#price .panel-default {

    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#size .panel-default {

    width: 100px;
    font-size: 188px;
}
```

All the CSS / HTML I know is self taught so I may be missing something fundamental here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try #price.panel-default instead. (without the space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS selector has an extra space between `price` and `panel-default` so it's basically looking for a child with `class="panel-default"` inside a div with `id="price"`. To get the selector to look for a div with `id="price"` and `class="panel-default"` remove the space between `#price` and `.panel-default`. Try:

```css
#price.panel-default {

    width: 150px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#size.panel-default {

    width: 100px;
    font-size: 188px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I already tried that. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBremerkamp I know the feeling. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

When you put a space between `#price` and `.panel-default` you're telling the CSS to look for a child object of `id="price"` with `class="panel-default"`.

What you want is this:

```css
#price.panel-default{
   ...
}
```

Without the space it's looking for one object with both the class and id

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces:

```css
#price.panel-default
#size.panel-default
```

`#price .panel-default` means some block with class `panel-default` that is in another block with id `price`.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting a CSS, `#size.panel-default` is different from `#size .panel-default`.

`#size.panel-default` could select an element that contains both id `size` and class `panel-default`:

```
<div id="size" class="panel-default"> <-- This is selected -->
</div>
```

while `#size .panel-default` select an element that has class `panel-default` and has a parent element with id `size`:

```
<div id="size">
  <div class="panel-default"> <-- This is selected -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Therefore the correct CSS for your case would be:

```css
#price.panel-default {
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#size.panel-default {
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 188px;
}
```